# recaptcha symfony2 form edit

Tags: symfony, recaptcha

i have a form for edit a user and in the class User i have

```
    /**
     * @Recaptcha\IsTrue
     */
    public $recaptcha;
```

and my FormType :

```
        $builder
    ->add('email', 'email', array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Email'), 'label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
    ->add('firstname', null, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Nom'), 'label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
    ->add('lastname', null, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Prénom'), 'label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
    ->add('telephone', 'number', array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Téléphone'), 'label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle', 'constraints' => array(
    new NotBlank(),
    new Length(array('min' => 8, 'max' => 8)),
    ), ))
    ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('m' => 'Moniteur', 's' => 'Secrétaire'),
    'label' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'mapped' => false
    ))
    ->add('adress', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Adresse'), 'label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
    ->add('cin', null, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'CIN'), 'label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle', 'constraints' => array(
    new NotBlank(),
    new Length(array('min' => 8, 'max' => 8)),
    ), ))
    ->remove('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha')
    ;
}
```

i removed it but the error message still how to desactivate it ? 
    the error message returned when i add a new user : This value is not a valid captcha.

Comment: "the error message"?

Comment: i'm sorry the error message is :     This value is not a valid                       captcha. symfony2 takes recaptcha for validation i don't know why